# SwiftUI - DatePicker-style like in Apple Calendar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, datepicker

I am trying to build a DatePicker which has a design like the Apple Calendar DatePicker, when you make a new calendar entry and click on the date/time: The DatePicker pops up **under** the line of the chosen date.

What I achived so far is that the DatePicker appears in the same line of the list. This does work, but doesn't feel smooth. Additionally I want the first DatePicker to close, when the other one gets opened and can't find a command to do it programatically in SwiftUI:

```
List {                        
     Section(header:Text("Notification")){
        HStack {
            Text("Activate")
            Spacer()
            Toggle(isOn: toggle) {Text("") }
        }
        HStack {
            Text("Mo. - Do.")
            Spacer()
            
            DatePicker("", selection: dateMoDo, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .colorInvert()
                .colorMultiply(Color.red)
                .labelsHidden()
        }
        HStack {
            Text("Freitags")
            Spacer()
            
            DatePicker("", selection: dateFr, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .colorInvert()
                .colorMultiply(Color.red)
                .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
  }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date Picker understand were to keep Data and related Title. You do not need to add additional Text

[image]

Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedDate = Date()
   var body: some View {
            Form {
                   Section {
                       DatePicker(
                           selection: $selectedDate,
                           displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute,
                           label: { Text("Mo. - Do.") }
                        ).colorInvert().colorMultiply(Color.red)

                        DatePicker(
                           selection: $selectedDate,
                           displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute,
                           label: { Text("Freitags") }
                        ).colorInvert().colorMultiply(Color.red)

                   }
               }
   }
}
```